# Min Height and Scrolling Divs

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I thought I'd ask.

I have a div layout which is two columns inside a div container. These are lined up using inline-block and percentage widths.

The basic layout is as so

```
<div id="containter" style="width:100%">

<div id="leftDiv" style="width:20%; height:100%; display:inline-block; overflow-y:scroll">
     List of Content
</div>

<div id="rightDiv" style="width:80%; height:100%; display:inline-block; min-height:500px; vertical-align:top">
     Some expanding information
</div>

</div>
```

Okay, so this basic layout works great. The problem i'm having is, as you might have noticed I have an overflow on the left column and a min-height on the right column. The idea is that the left column will display a list of items, however I don't ever want that list to stretch the height of the containing div, I want it to fit into 100% of the containing div and scroll.

I would however like the content in the right hand div to be able to stretch the height of the container div when it grows however always having a minimum height of 500px and the left hand div to grow with it.

For the time being I'm going to write a javascript fix, however I would like to find out if this is possible to do this in pure css. Maybe there is something new in CSS3/HTML5 which would help?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: the famous 100% height div... My solution for this is faux backgrounds only, nout a *proper* CSS solution for your problem though...

Comment: Yes indeed! There must be a way to do this in CSS, I'm hoping some genius out there knows it. Using height 100% can be so counter intuitive at times!

Comment: I found this: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200405/equal_height_boxes_with_css/ and it does work, but as stated there, it isn't supported in IE...

Comment: Can't be done without `display: table`.

Answer (score 4):

`display:table;` doesn't actually do it. The question as asked wants the left column to scroll, rather than boosting the length of the document. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPZRt/2/) for an illustration of the problem.

The only way that I'm aware of to force `overflow: scroll` to work is to define a height; `max-height:500px;` works [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/BPZRt/3/), but you can't set `100%` without getting garbage results.

It looks like to get both the layout and the scrolling your js solution is the necessary one.